# iOS 8 ActionSheet Color

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why my actionSheet looks like this

[image]

I am building my code from Xcode 4.5.1 with build target 6.1. Then when i build it in iPad running iOS 8 beta then the action sheet looks like this.Can any one help on this issue.
Here is the code

```
 self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    [self.actionSheet setDelegate:self];
    [self.actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button1"];
    [self.actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Button 2"];
    [self.actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:actionButton animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

according to this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html thread 
UIActionSheet is deprecated, you should use UIAlertController instead of UIActionSheet.
Thanks.